# Magento 2 - Automatic currency and manual currency

Tags: magento2, currency, product-prices

A client has a multistore. For convenience he has store A and store B. Store A uses the euro, which is also the base currency, and store B (UK) uses the British pounds.
(They are differentiated on website scope)

The store is currently setup so it automatically converts the euro's to british pounds. Now the customer wants to be able to set different prices for store B, based on the British pound, for only a handful of products.

Now to to that I switched the price scope to website (Config -> Catalog -> Catalog Price Scope). But after a reindex it now takes the value filled in on the default scope and sets it as the price value for store B. (So a product that was 10 euros, converted to 8 pounds for example, is now 10 euros and 10 pounds).

My question is:
Is there a way (or custom module you know of) to get the best of both worlds?
So

1. Per default it converts and sets the price for Store from Euro's to British pounds.
2. Only if the customer wants a different price for that UK store, it can adjust it and it will use that price instead of the price based on currency rates. He can do this within a product on the correct scope.